# Why are my Maori units automatically healing?

Tags: civilization-6

A few times in this game a Maori unit has automatically healed itself. This one was down in the red, it just got attacked, then at the start of the next turn it was fully healed.

I didn't promote it, I did nothing at all, it's just magically healed.

Any idea why? I can find nothing about this online. I haven't played as the Maori for months but I don't remember this happening before.

[image: a Maori unit stationed next to Antawaylla, the city]

Comment: What expansions/mods are you running?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your unit rested/fortified/waited a turn next to the [Dead Sea](https://civ6.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Sea) natural wonder. This wonder provides full healing to all adjacent units.

Comment: YES that must be it, well spotted. Not sure how I've never noticed this before, I guess the chances of being in combat and finishing a turn with depleted health right next to it is slim. Kind of sucks for the defending player tho potentially. It would be nice if the game TOLD you this is what happened.

Comment: Wow, so being Maori is totally irrelevant, and Civ Fandom is incomplete. mmm

Comment: Putting a city where Antawaylla is seems like a pretty daft move then. Even if the defender puts a unit there, there are at least 2 melee and another 2 ranged positions that can target the defending unit and have the same benefits.

Comment: @Mast Yeah if you have a city with the Dead Sea in your territory you MUST have defenders next to it to prevent attackers monopolizing it. I guess the AI isn't smart enough to know this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make a Pā? I can't see one, but I don't play, so maybe I'm just blind. And I'm just working off what the Wiki gives me.

Here's the wiki's article on [Pā](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/M%C4%81ori_(Civ6)#P.C4.81). They give healing to the culture's units if they end on it.

And here's the wiki's article on [Healing](https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Combat_(Civ6)#Healing), if it's not a Pā.

Comment: There doesn't look like Pā existing. Even if it exists at somewhere out of this screenshot, it won't heal red health to full health(It only heals "*A Māori unit that ends its turn on this improvement **heals 10 HP*** and *If the unit Fortifies Until Healed on the Pā, it only **heals 15 HP** if within friendly territory and **10 HP** if in neutral or enemy territory*.) All of unit in Civ6 has 100HP at first, so 10/15 HP healing can't heal enough to full health in just a turn.

Comment: @Skye-AT - Oh. Right. I couldn't see a Pā either. I should've made a comment instead... And this doesn't help me form an answer: https://civilization.fandom.com/wiki/Combat_(Civ6)#Healing

Comment: There's no Pa but not a bad idea.